# Calculate complete function from imaginary part in raman response

Tags: raman-spectroscopy

When I want to calculate the raman response function $R$ from the molecular responses $g_a$ and $g_b$, I have to use the functions
$$g_n(\Omega) = 2\gamma f_r\text{Im}\left[\tilde{R}_n\left(\Omega\right)\right]\text{ with } n = a, b$$
$\tilde{R}$ is the fourier transformation of $R$. My problem is now that thanks to several papers I know that I can calculate $g_n$ if I have $R$, but I do not know how to calculate $R$ if I have $g_n$, because of the $\text{Im}[]$-part. Is there a way to calculate the real part of $\tilde{R}$ out of $g$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very much like you want to use [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) to relate the real and imaginary parts of the Raman response function.  Now I don't much care for the Wikipedia entry on Kramers-Kronig but it is a start. I prefer either Boyd's Nonlinear Optics (most other discussions will only cover the linear case).

This article

Kramers–Kronig relations and resonance Raman scattering
Hassing, S. and Mortensen, O. Sonnich, The Journal of Chemical Physics, 73, 1078-1083 (1980), DOI:http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.440280

seems like it would be a good start too.